# php Ajax jquery check

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hi every body  i was testing a code for checking name availability with ajax and i dont now why its doesnt work

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<title>index</title>

</head>
```

this is the body and the jquery function
    
    
    
    check

```
<div id="answer" > 

<script type="text/javascript">
//script
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkme").click(function(){
    $("#answer").ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).text("loading .. .").show("slow");
    });
    var Userme = $("#username").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:GET,
        url:"file.php",
        data:"username=" + Userme,
        success: function(msg){ $("#answer").text(msg).fadeIn("slow");}
    });


    });
});
</script>
</div></form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is php code

```
    <?php
$names = array (A,B,C,D);
$username = $_GET['username'];

if(in_array ($username , $names)){

    echo "ok";

    }else{


        echo "doesnt exist ";


        }

?>
```

plz help

im new with jquery and ajax and i cant guess the mistake i hope you can help me

Comment: Use firebug and check what is getting passed in the url

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get 'doesnt exist' back? or some other error?

Comment: i get nothing every time i click page refresh and nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly the problem is as I can see multiple errors.

In your javascript code:

`type:GET` should be `type: "get"`

`data:"username=" + Userme` should be `data: {username: Userme}`

In your PHP code:

`$names = array (A,B,C,D);` should be `$names = array ("A", "B", "C", "D");`

Comment: its work when i change the event from check.click to user.change